# SSL certificates not updated on old Android

Tags: https

I have an old Android smartphones. More and more websites stop working because my chrome browser doesn't trust the root CA (Outdated or missing CA certificates). Obviously the root CA list is only updated via an android os update.

Any ideas how I can migate the problem? (Beside adding them manually / buying a new phone) Lineageos isn't supported as well.

Comment: You could try a different browser. Would that work?

Comment: The Firefox works... But it has its own cert store. Changing the browser won't help with apps that also requires trust on ssl certificates.

Comment: How old is that smartphone? Usually you can add your own CA certificates in the settings.

Comment: @firendlyQuestion Please edit your question and say exactly what Smartphone you are talking about (brand, model and Android version). Anyway if your phone is that old you should be able to root it and the edit the certificate list.